# PDO states I am missing tokens, But I am not - what's wrong with this

Tags: php, pdo

So I have managed to spit out (through `var_dump`) the following:

```
// This is my whole select statement
string 'SELECT * FROM logs AS LOG WHERE ( LOG.DATE BETWEEN :startMonth AND :endMonth ) AND LOG.VALUE LIKE :filter ' (length=106)

// This is the database object (note the params)
object(Micro\Database)[1667]
  protected 'query' => string 'SELECT * FROM logs AS LOG WHERE ( LOG.DATE BETWEEN :startMonth AND :endMonth ) ' (length=79)
  protected 'params' => 
    array
      ':startMonth' => 
        object(DateTime)[1668]
          public 'date' => string '2014-06-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
      ':endMonth' => 
        object(DateTime)[1671]
          public 'date' => string '2014-06-30 23:59:59' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
      ':filter' => string '%"unit_id": 1030006431%' (length=23)
```

So in the query we see that I am using `:startMonth`, `:endMonth` and `:filter` and then in the params We see I am setting the same variables. everything should be there. But apparently it's not:

`'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'`

Uh .... no all the tokens are there. Let look at the code

```
public static function findByWildCard($unitId=null, $messageType=null, $filter=null, $month) {
    $sqlSelect = 'SELECT * ' .
                    'FROM logs AS LOG '.
                    'WHERE ( LOG.DATE BETWEEN :startMonth AND :endMonth ) ';


    // Connect to lazarus
    $query = self::connectToLazarus();

    // Start of the specified month. Eg. 2013-01-01 00:00:00
    $startMonth = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $month.' 00:00:00');

    // End of the specified month. Eg. 2013-01-31 11:59:59
    $endMonth = clone $startMonth;
    $oneMonth = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
    $oneSecond = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 second');
    $endMonth->add($oneMonth)->sub($oneSecond);

    // Get the results from the query
    $query->setQuery($sqlSelect)
        ->setParameter('startMonth', $startMonth)
        ->setParameter('endMonth', $endMonth);

    if (!empty($filter)) {
        $sqlSelect .= 'AND LOG.VALUE LIKE :filter ';
        $query->setParameter('filter', '%'.$filter.'%');
    }

    var_dump($query->getResult()); exit;

}
```

What is going on?

Comment: There's little sense changing `$sqlSelect` - it's already used in `setQuery`. Place `if(!empty($filter))` _before_ `$query->setQuery` block.

Comment: It's pretty clear from the first code sample that the ` AND LOG.VALUE LIKE :filter` clause is missing from your SQL in the database object. I'm not sure what the relationship is between that first example and the code you posted and why it's not there, but that's where I'd start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the query before you add the filter to the query string.

```
// Get the results from the query
$query->setQuery($sqlSelect)
    ->setParameter('startMonth', $startMonth)
    ->setParameter('endMonth', $endMonth);

if (!empty($filter)) {
    $sqlSelect .= 'AND LOG.VALUE LIKE :filter ';
    $query->setParameter('filter', '%'.$filter.'%');
}
```

You are setting the query to $sqlSelect and aftwards appending the filter part after setting the query but never setting the query again to the new value.

Comment: @YourCommonSense If I didn't, someone else would. I write this stuff in as comments all day long only to see someone 10 minutes later come by and post it as an answer and collect points. Meh, it's all part of the gamification.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possible issues that may cause such a problem

1. A typo. Most of time you just misspell some variable or a placeholder name.
2. Number of tokens indeed mismatch number of variables. recount them.
3. Quite rare case when you are using a placeholder with the same name ina several places in the query. To solve this one, just turn emulation mode on.